# Compare a form field with a String variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
String password = (String)session.getAttribute("password");
<input type = "password" placeholder = "Type your current password"  id = "pass"  />
```

Now, I want to compare the value in the form field with the variable "password".How can I do so by using JavaScript?

Comment: where's your variable 'password' - Javascript/Html or Java? Your snippet looks like a combination of both.

Comment: There is no dataType `String` in `javaScript`. use `var`

Comment: @Navin I'm using JSP.So I've put "String password" statement inside a scriplet.

Comment: @VishalChugh your problem is solved?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone                                            An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /profile.jsp
String cannot be resolved to a variable
    27: <script>
    28: function f1
    29: {
    30: var password=<%(String)session.getAttribute("password");%>;
    31: var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
    32: if(pass.value != password)
    33:  alert("Wrong Password");

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone same error:"String cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @VishalChugh check now..i have updated

Comment: Apart from technical considerations, it is a really bad idea to check a password client-side: Your HTML will contain the **plain text password**, so all I need to do is ask my browser to display the page source, then look up the password in it, and enter it in your input field. Voilà. Better post the user input to the server and compare it there!

Answer (score 0):

do this

html file

```
<input type = "password" placeholder = "Type your current password"  id = "pass"  />
```

Script.js

```
var password="<%session.getAttribute("password");%>";
var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value; 
return pass.equals(password);
```

Comment: just return the `pass.equals(password)` to have true/false result.

Comment: @KarelG i didnt get u?

Comment: you are using obsolete if/else blocks because the `equals()` method gives a `true` or `false` as result. Just do `return pass.equals(password);` for same result.